# In Symfony4 update function not working,after values fetch from database

Tags: mysql, symfony, twig, symfony1, symfony4

I'm new to Symfony.I made a form with 
    insert,delete,view,update. In view page i added a edit button which is used 
    to update the values.when i submit the form after change the values in form 
    values will not updated in output.Please share your thoughts.

Thank You...

here i attached my controller code

```
/** 
* @Route("/update/{id}", name="update") 
*/ 
//edit function
public function edit($id,Request $request,Ramsurath $ramsurath) :Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(RamsurathType::class, $ramsurath);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
        {
          $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
          return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
        }
    return $this->render('ramsurath/update.html.twig',        
    ['ramsurath'=>$ramsurath,'form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the Symfony Documentation for [Processing Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms).

You are missing the call to `$form->getData()` before flushing:

```php
/** 
* @Route("/update/{id}", name="update") 
*/ 
//edit function
public function edit($id,Request $request,Ramsurath $ramsurath) :Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(RamsurathType::class, $ramsurath);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
        {
          $ramsurath = $form->getData(); // this is the line you are missing
          $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
          return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
        }
    return $this->render('ramsurath/update.html.twig',        
   ['ramsurath'=>$ramsurath,'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
    }
```